# Fixed text when scrolling

Tags: abap

My program displays an ABAP list, I'm trying to show a header (some lines of text, nothing fancy) fixed when scrolling down in a report.

Is there some kind of tag or declaration that I have to use?

Comment: What kind of output - "legacy" list output, ALV Grid, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `SE38` you can define list heading with 'GOTO -> Text Elements -> List Headings`.
[image: Maintenance screen for list headers]

You can define a list header, and titles for your list (Columns heading).

One advantage: With `GOTO -> Translations` you can define different texts in different languages.

Another way to get this maintenance screen:

From your list, you can choose: `System -> List -> List Header`. 
[image: List screen: System -> List -> List Header]
[image: Define title texts]

---

Another way:

You can use `top-of-page` to define your header text inside your report code.

```
top-of-page.
  write 'My header'.
```

Comment: @Eva A remark: You wrote `fixed when scrolling`. The methods in this answer works fine with printing, and it defines header lines. But I works only with _new pages_. Scolling down on an _endless_ list does not make new pages (instead of printing). You may combine the solutions with `REPORT PAGE-SIZE 25` to force pages with 25 lines.

Comment: Thank you. I already had that "PAGE-SIZE 25" in the code, but, because i'm new at this, didn't understand what could it do, so it was commented.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TOP OF PAGE event to write something that will stick at the top of the page while scrolling. You can find more info [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/9f/dba02835c111d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm).

You can also use the list headers from Text Elements menu. More info [here](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_bw/helpdata/en/e3/960a05eb0711d194d100a0c94260a5/content.htm).

Best regards,
Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

One way is directly using top-of-page in your code.

Other way is calling reuse_alv_grid_display or reuse_alv_list_display (depending on your output type) and declaring "top-of-page" in the I_CALLBACK_TOP_OF_PAGE line. Then create a sub-routine with the same name as your "top-of-page". In that you can write
wa_list-typ = 'H'.
  wa_list-info = ''.
  APPEND wa_list to it_list.
  clear wa_list.

OR

wa_list-typ = 'A'.
  wa_list-info = 'Report Header'.
  APPEND wa_list to it_list.
  clear wa_list.

OR

wa_list-typ = 'S'.
  wa_list-info = 'Report Header'.
  APPEND wa_list to it_list.
  clear wa_list.

depending on what you want (header, action or selection).

Finally you can use REUSE_ALV_COMMENTARY_WRITE function and call the table(in this example it_list).

Hope it helped.